# What is the most efficient format for storing strings from a for loop?

Tags: string, matlab

I have a script that runs through a series of strings and using regex pulls out certain strings (approx 4 output strings per input string).

```
e.g. HelloStackOverflowWorld
->   Hello; Stack; Overflow; World;
```

The final output would ideally be a table where I can filter based upon the strings in the columns. Using the case above, column 1 row 1 would have `'Hello'`, column 2 row 1 would have `'Stack'` and so on.

The problem is, the size of the output will change depending on the input so I am unsure of what output format to use.

At the moment I used something similar to this:

```
if strfind(missing{ii},'hello')
    miss.exch = [miss.exch;'hello'];
    temp.exc = regexp(missing{ii},'(?<=\d[Q|T])(\w*?)(?=[q])','match');
    miss.exc = [miss.exc;temp.exc];
    temp.TQ= regexp(missing{ii},'(Qc|Tc)','match');
    if strcmp(temp.TQ{1,1}, 'Tc')
        miss.TQ = [miss.TQ;'variableA'];
    elseif temp.TQ{1,1} == 'Qc'
        miss.TQ = [miss.TQ;'variableB'];
    end
else if .........
end
```

Which obviously results in a 1x1 struct consisting of a number of fields each with many cells. This makes filtering on strings an issue!

How can I define and add data into a `'table of strings'` that I can then filter?

Comment: check out the `cell()` datatype. He allows you to save any format inside a cell, thus you could save each of those strings in respectively cells. As a matter of fact `cell(A,B)` constructs a cell of dimension AxB. And if you want to adress the data inside a cell or append data to a cell you should used curly brackets `{}`. E.g. if A is your cell array you could do `A{1}='Hello'` or `A(1)={'Hello'}`. To get the entry back just use `A{1}`. Good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are just looking for a cell array. Here is a simple example of what they can do:

```
C = {'Abc','Bcd';'Cde',[]}

strcmp(C,'Cde')
```

Results in:

```
ans =

     0     0
     1     0
```

Make sure to check `doc cell` to see how you can access them.

Comment: Ah it was, thankyou! I ended up preallocating a cell array and assigning the output strings to different columns of each row.